# Redirect a URL with querystring to to a new URL with same querystring

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I currently have the following in my `.htaccess` file that redirects all requests to the SSL version of the site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.mydomain.com$1 [R=301,nc]
```

Now, I'd like to redirect calls to my current root URL - **only when it has a querystring attached** - to a new url with the same querystring. Example:

`https://www.mydomain.com/?foo=bar` redirected to:

`https://www.mydomain.com/new_mapping/?foo=bar`

Whereas requests without a querystring continue to go to `https://www.mydomain.com/`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  a `RewriteCond` to match a nonempty query string with `.+` and rewrite it with `[QSA]`

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the querystring has at least 1 character
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+
# Rewrite requests to the root 
RewriteRule ^/?$ new_mapping [L,QSA]
```

If you want to actually redirect the browser to show the new URL, use `[R=301]`. The `[QSA]` is technically not necessary then, because the query string will automatically be appended for a redirect.

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ new_mapping [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be doing anything. Should I place it in a certain place in relation to my current `RewriteRule`?

Comment: @AbidA It should be placed after your SSL redirect.  I'll also change it to `^/?$ though that should not be necessary.  To debug, remove the RewriteCond and verify that the root URL rule is matched, then add back the RewriteCond.

Comment: Now I'm getting a 400 Bad request. Everything seems to work fine, except when the querystring is applied to the root URL.

Comment: Oh, so I added the complete URL `https://www.mydomain.com/new_mapping` and that worked.